# admob refresh rate programmatically

Tags: ios, admob, ads

In the admob site in application settings there is config for banner refresh rate, and one of options is 'Use refresh rate set in client code'

but in client code i couldn't find the way how to set refresh rate, is there any property or method for that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no setting for `refresh rate in client code`. There was something like this in the very legacy AdMob (versions before 4.0), but is not at all in the current Android AdMob SDK nor the Mobile Ads APIs in Google Play services. This option stuck around in the legacy AdMob UI, but is not an option with the new AdMob UI on [apps.admob.com](http://apps.admob.com).